# Qual é a quantidade máxima que um array pode suportar em PHP?

Tags: php, array, memória

No PHP eu costumo trabalhar muito com *frameworks*. Geralmente, os mesmos trazem os resultados da consulta a um banco de dados em um `array`.

Em alguns casos, quando o número de dados de uma tabela ou um relacionamento chega a um nível muito grande, se não utilizarmos recursos como paginação ou um AJAX *lazy load*, pode acontecer aquele erro.

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 99999999 bytes exhausted
```

já houve casos que, comigo, um *array* grande demais gerou esse erro, mas isso pode variar de uma configuração do php.ini (`memory_limit`) para outra. Porém, geralmente sempre existe um valor padrão para o limite de memória - Que no caso é 128M para versões iguais ou superiores ao PHP 5.3.

Levando em consideração a predefinição de `128M`, seria possível chegar a um cálculo, para saber mais ou menos, qual é a quantidade de dados que poderíamos usar num `array`?

Existe um tamanho máximo recomendado para eu alocar valores em um  `array`?

Comment: Wallace se uma array chega a essa quantidade alguma coisa está muito mal no seu código ;)

Comment: @JorgeB. sim, com certeza. Só aconteceu isso com o `Codeigniter` até hoje, rsrsrsrs.

Comment: @JorgeB. nem sempre. Pode ser um input alterado pelo console e criar algo como: `<input name="q[][][]" type="text" />`, e fazer um input ter N índices alterando o atributo `name` com centenas de `[]`.

Comment: Cabe ao desenvolvedor trabalhar os dados, eu sei, mas é só um exemplo de que um array pode ser de uma fonte externa. Como padrão aboli array dos formulários, incluindo checkbox's.

Comment: @PapaCharlie e, pelo fato de ser forma externa, você pode "injetar" um array gigante, para gerar um erro. Eu já consegui fazer isso, com um formulário suicída.

Comment: @PapaCharlie mas aqui estamos a falar de arrays vindos da base de dados, pelo menos foi isso que eu entendi.

Comment: @JorgeB. array vindo da base de dados foi só um exemplo. Na verdade, citei, pois é uma das formas que é mais fácil de você gerar um erro por exaustão de memória. Outras fontes de arrays são "aceitas para a resposta", mas não me lembro de uma que possa impactar tanto como a do banco de dados.

Comment: @JorgeB., foi só um adendo

Comment: @WallaceMaxters, também já manipulei o meu em ambiente de teste e por isso aboli array em form.

Comment: @PapaCharlie mas não adianta muita coisa. O cara que editar seu formulário, pode adicionar  um `array` lá. Já consegui bugar um sistema de  um cara assim ;0

Comment: @WallaceMaxters, provavelmente sua vítima usava algo tipo `htmlspecialchars` direto com o valor do `$_POST`. No meu caso se o valor for um array eu faço um casting pra valor null.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

O problema nesse caso não é o *array*, é a quantidade total de memória. Ao contrário da crença popular, o *array* não inclui tudo o que pode parecer estar nele. Muito provavelmente vários dados que estão nele são referências, então só haverá um ponteiro no *array*, mas o objeto referenciado é que realmente está ocupando memória. E esse dado pode ser variável. Um *array* precisa ter seus elementos com tamanho fixo, por isso que o ponteiro precisa ser usado para garantir, assim normaliza o tamanho igual para todos os elementos e com essa [indireção](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181032/101) a variação de tamanho vai para outro objeto apontado.

É possível até saber quantos elementos cabem no *array*, mas isso não resolve o problema descrito, não tem relevância e é uma informação que não vai ajudar.

Se está com problemas então tem que mudar a forma como manipula esses dados e saber quantos elementos podem ser usados no *array* não ajuda em nada. Inclusive porque isso pode mudar em cada execução ou pelo menos ao longo do tempo de vida do projeto.

Até é possível fazer um cálculo na hora para saber se vai caber na memória ou não, mas não compensa o esforço, provavelmente vai ter dois trabalhos, um para verificar se cabe e outro para por na memória de fato. É melhor [dividir e conquistar](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divis%C3%A3o_e_conquista) logo. Se há o potencial de estourar a memória não deixe isto acontecer parcelando o processamento.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Conceptual.md).