# O que é indireção?

Tags: terminologia, engenharia-de-software, ciência-da-computação

Leio em alguns lugares sobre programação que algo faz ou deveria fazer uma indireção.

O que é isto e para que serve?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

É o ato de fazer referência para alguma coisa *indiretamente*, ou seja, através de algo que não seja o seu valor. É uma forma de delegação. Usamos isso em programação o tempo todo sem perceber.

Uma [**variável**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181332/101) é uma indireção. Poderíamos acessar uma posição da memória, mas usamos um nome que nos leva a essa posição da memória. Isso dá uma flexibilidade bem grande, podemos até mesmo trocar o endereço de memória dessa variável e ela permanecer a mesma referência. Não que sempre seja possível, mas é uma possibilidade.

Uma [**função**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/122429/101) é outra das mais usadas. A função nada mais é que um nome que referencia uma posição de memória onde tem um código. O uso direto é acessar o código logo ali, mas o que fazemos é indicar onde o código está. É um acesso indireto, portanto é uma indireção.

Um [**delegado**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/34907/101) é uma indireção da indireção. Ele é uma variável ou objeto mais complexo que possui um endereço onde tem a informação que indica qual é a função a ser executada, portanto é um nível de indireção em cima de outro.

O [**polimorfismo**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/153042/101) (pelo menos um dos tipos) é outra forma de indireção da indireção, já que para saber o que chamar, precisa consultar uma tabela do que deve ser executado. A primeira referência é onde está a tabela daquele tipo e depois pega a referência para o método correto.

Um [**objeto em memória dinâmica**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101) é uma indireção porque você acessa um valor que indica onde está o objeto.

Quando você não sabe o tamanho do objeto até a sua criação durante a execução, precisa criar uma indireção, o que é muito comum em [*strings*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/164729/101).

Um [*array* simples](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/124849/101) é uma indireção. Ele funciona como uma variável de uma variável. A variável primária é o *array* como um todo, a variável secundária é o elemento individual dele.

Um [***array* de objetos variados**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/180783/101) pode fazer uma indireção para compatibilização dos tipos. Na verdade isso vale para qualquer estrutura. Uma linguagem de tipagem dinâmica faz isso.

Sabe os famosos [***getters* e *setters***](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/133924/101)? É uma indireção onde se usa uma função no lugar de uma variável. Já sabemos que a variável é uma indireção. A função é outro tipo de indireção sendo usada com um objetivo específico de nova abstração.

Uma classe ou método recebe um objeto para parametrizá-lo. Este objeto é que tem a implementação concreta que a classe ou método precisa. **[Inversão de dependência](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21319/101)** é só mais um exemplo de indireção.

[**Linkagem dinâmica**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/149372/101) precisa da indireção para fazer a ligação.

Estes são apenas alguns exemplos óbvios.

A indireção pode [evitar desvios condicionais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/135702/101) que podem ter um custo de processamento alto.

Em geral a indireção ocorre através de um [ponteiro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/175967/101), mesmo que não pareça um.

Com ela produzimos código mais [DRY](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/120931/101). Você tem a informação em um lugar e pode fazer várias referências a ela.

OOP usa e abusa de indireção. Especialmente quando usa os famosos padrões de projeto criados para solucionar os problemas que OOP causou. A indireção vem para salvar a pátria.

A indireção pode ocorrer em níveis mais abstratos. O uso de uma biblioteca, de um *webservice*, de um *driver*, tudo pode ser um indireção. O acesso à memória e a todo hardware pelas aplicações é uma indireção. O acesso é indireto através de um mecanismo intermediário disponibilizado.

A indireção é fundamental para criar abstrações, desde as mais simples, como a variável, até as mais complexas. É tão importante que é chamado de ["Teorema Fundamental da Engenharia de Software"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_software_engineering).

> Não existe problema na computação que não possa ser resolvido com um nível extra de indireção
>
> -- David J. Wheeler

Na verdade a frase ficou famosa na mão do Butler Lampson. Portanto a citação é uma indireção... :)

É óbvio que existem exageros no seu uso, até porque em geral não pensamos muito na indireção, estamos só à procura de uma solução para o problema. Não pensamos em não causar outro problema. Quando você delega demais começa ter duplicação de esforços e começa aumentar a complexidade. Por isso costuma-se complementar a citação acima com:

> ... exceto para o problema de níveis demais de indireção

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).